# Creating Json file from mysql

Tags: mysql, json

i can't get more than one return in this json. when the original query returns 90k results.

i can't figure out what's hapening.

also the return i get isn't organized as it should. it return the following

{"material":["R8190300000","0"],"grid":["R8190300000","0"]}

sorry to ask this i have been looking for an answer but couln't get it in the internet.

```
<?php


$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","blablabla","blablabla","blablabla");

if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
die("Could not connect to database");
}

$query =" SELECT material,grid FROM ZATPN";


if( $result = mysqli_query( $link, $query)){

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))  {


    $resultado['material']=$row;
    $resultado['grid']=$row;


}    

} else {

echo"doesnt work";

}


file_put_contents("data.json", json_encode($resultado));




?>
```

Comment: Focus on the code in the `while` block. This is where you fail to create the desired data structure.

Comment: yeah lets make riddle or just tell him that he overwrites his resultado in every row.

Comment: ... and he is adding the entire row to both the components material and grid, explaining the result {"material":["R8190300000","0"],"grid":["R8190300000","0"]}

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are overriding the value for the array keys:

```
$resultado['material']=$row;
$resultado['grid']=$row;
```

At the end you will have only the last 2 rows; I suggest you to use something like:

```
$resultado['material'][] = $row;
$resultado['grid'][] = $row;
```

This will save you pair rows in `$resultado['grid']` and unpaired rows in `$resultado['material']`;

After the information in comments you can use this code:

```
$allResults = array();
while ($object = mysqli_fetch_object($result))  {

    $resultado['id'] = $object->id;
    $resultado['name'] = $object->name;
    $resultado['item'] = $object->item;
    $resultado['price'] = $object->price;
    $allResults[] = $resultado;
}    

file_put_contents("data.json", json_encode($allResults));
```

Comment: the result i need is something like this:[
    {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Item 0",
        "price": "$0"
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Item 1",
        "price": "$1"
    },  what i got was {"material":[["02390M00101","42"],["02390M00101","41"],["02390M00101","40"],

Comment: @Madehhh I think it was supposed to be an example, not a literal solution.